# How to use multiple data types within the same ADT in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

For example, if I defined a Stack ADT in C, normally my type definition -using an array based implementation- is like this:

```
typedef char StackEntry;

typedef struct stack {
    int top;
    StackEntry entry[MAXSTACK];
} Stack;
```

How can I make my Stack such that I can have one Stack for characters and another Stack -in the same program- that handles integers for example ?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about generics.  They don't exist in C, though you can emulate them to some extent via macros.

Comment: You'd have to implement something like C++ templates using macros (because that's the only metaprogramming facility C supports).

Comment: You can implement it for generic types as long they have equal sizes. (Non-heterogeneous, that is. Or: us pointers and smart unions)

Comment: It is usually done by *providing* the needed operations (in form of function pointers), like assignment, comparison, allocation, deallocation and others when creating the specific ADT instance.

Comment: @melpomene Generic data structures are definitely possible to implement in C without using macros.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If you store `void *` internally, that's not a generic structure. How else are you going to do it?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad for SO.  We answer questions about specific, narrowly-defined programming problems; open-ended how-to questions are [not appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: The functions will work with `void *` indeed. But as noted, when creating the data structure all of the basic operations on the underlying type are provided.

Comment: Since this is just a "dumb" ADT, it doesn't _need_ to know the type. The ADT in itself will not do anything with the data apart from shovelling it around. Therefore it might make most sense to just use a `uint8_t` array of raw data which you allocate dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stack-structure that is initialized with the size of the elements and that reserves a memory block in terms of bytes to store the elements:

```
typedef struct stack {
    int top;
    size_t size;
    size_t maxElems;
    char content[];
} Stack;

Stack *createStack(size_t size, size_t maxElems) {
    Stack *result = malloc(sizeof(Stack)+size*maxElems);
    result->top=0;
    result->size=size;
    result->maxElems=maxElems;
    return result;
}

int push(Stack *stack, void *elem) {
    if (stack->top == stack->maxElems)
        return -1;

    memcpy(stack->content + stack->top * stack->size, elem, stack->size);
    stack->top++;
    return stack->top;
}

int pop(Stack *stack, void *elem) {
    if (stack->top == 0)
        return -1;

    stack->top--;
    memcpy(elem, stack->content + stack->top * stack->size, stack->size);
    return stack->top;
}

int main() {

    Stack *charStack = createStack(sizeof(char), 10);
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        char c = 'A'+i;
        push(charStack, &c);
    }
    char c;
    while (pop(charStack, &c) >= 0) {
        printf("%c\n", c);
    }
    free(charStack);

    Stack *intStack = createStack(sizeof(int), 10);
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        push(intStack, &i);
    }
    int i;
    while (pop(intStack, &i) >= 0) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    free(intStack);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use macros, e.g.

```
#define STACK_TYPE(type) struct { int top; type entry[MAXSTACK]; }
```

You may well end up using macros for the stack operations such as push/pop too:

```
#define STACK_PUSH(stack, value) \
    do { if ( (top) < MAXSTACK ) (stack).entry[(stack).top++] = (value); } while (0)
```

In most cases you wouldn't need to pass the stack type as a macro parameter, since the same syntax works for all stacks.

Sample usage:

```
STACK_TYPE(int) mystack = { 0 };
STACK_PUSH(mystack, 5);
```

Obviously there are a lot of different ways you could do the details.